# remove string after specific character

Tags: vba, excel

I found the following [function](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1783-excel-remove-text-before-character.html) that will remove any characters *before* a specified character.

However, I want to make it so that it removes all of the characters *after* the specified character.

Please can you help me achieve this.

```
Sub RemoveAllButLastWord()
'Updateby20140612
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim xChar As String
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
xChar = Application.InputBox("String", xTitleId, "", Type:=2)
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    xValue = Rng.Value
    Rng.Value = VBA.Right(xValue, VBA.Len(xValue) - VBA.InStrRev(xValue, xChar))
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: So loop through your range one cell at a time? Edit: `set rng=range("a1:a500") | for each c in rng`

Comment: Change `VBA.Right(xValue, VBA.Len(xValue) - VBA.InStrRev(xValue, xChar))` to `VBA.Left(xValue, VBA.InStrRev(xValue, xChar)-1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand everything that is happening in the code you gave, but it seems overly complicated to me. If I understand you correctly, you want to iterate through each cell in a range, and delete everything in the cell that occurs after a specific character. This is how I would do that:

```
Sub RemoveAllTextAfterChar()
Dim rWorkRange  As Range
Dim rng         As Range
Dim sChar       As String
Dim sOldValue   As String
Dim sNewValue   As String
Dim dCharNumber As Double

Set rWorkRange = ActiveSheet.Selection
sChar = InputBox("Enter the character")

For Each rng In rWorkRange        
    sOldValue = rng.value                  'Get cell value into a variable        
    dCharNumber = InStr(sOldValue, sChar)  'Use InStr function to find where the special character occurs
    If Not dCharNumber = 0 Then            'If character does not occur, do not change the cell            
        sNewValue = Mid(sOldValue, 1, dCharNumber)  'Create a new string that cuts off at the special character
        rng.value = sNewValue              'Replace original cell value with new, edited value
    End If
Next

Set rWorkRange = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

I have tightened the original code

```
Sub RemoveAllFirstLastWord()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim xChar As String
Dim lngPos As Long

Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", "KutoolsforExcel", Selection.Address, Type:=8)
xChar = Application.InputBox("String", xTitleId, "", Type:=2)

For Each Rng In WorkRng
    lngPos = InStr(Rng.Value, xChar)
    If lngPos > 0 Then Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = Left$(Rng.Value, lngPos - 1)
Next

End Sub
```